# Getting compilation error when trying to use openzeppelin for erc20 token

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I installed Openzeppelin framework and created a simple token sol file.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol";

contract SToken is MintableToken {
    string public constant name = "SS Token";
    string public constant symbol = "SKS";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 2;
}
```

When I tried compiling i am getting following error.

node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source "node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "./BasicToken.sol";

Any idea/thoughts what can be possible reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, you failed to install node modules properly. I tried using Remix online browser and could easily deploy your contract just changing from local node modules to point github repository of zeppelin.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol";

contract SToken is MintableToken {
    string public constant name = "SS Token";
    string public constant symbol = "SKS";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 2;
}
```

Deployment transaction : https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xe31ee332fca077398f562558fc43e1ee02eb9ba909c3be533593fff61539e613

Contract address : https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xb60f82f7c0967a54cd937f28014ea1614f931782

Comment: Thanks Mehmet.  Its working for me too using Remix. I had just run these commands : truffle init ,                                                                                        
                    npm init -y
                    npm install -E openzeppelin-solidity                                                  
         Any idea if I missed anything

Comment: I have free time for now and tried to run your code on my local. Now I understand what you have missed because I faced the same issue. You place your contract under contracts folder. Therefore, you must also set relative path for node modules. It will be resolved, if you import zeppelin contract as follows:  
``` import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol"; ```